# why in the Python interpreter the first indentation level is set to 4 space, while the second to 8?

Tags: python

let's take the really simple case of two nested `for` loops
after pressing return and tab the first time, I get an indentation level where 1 tab equals 4 spaces
after pressing return and tab the second time, I get an indentation level where 1 tab equals 9 spaces

this is rather annoying when I want to copy a piece of code from a script and run it on the interpreter, as it returns the
`TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

I did some googling but you can imagine what the keywords "python", "interpreter", "indentation" returns: nothing useful

Is there a way to correct this? Thanks

[image]

**EDIT**
just try yourselves:
open a terminal
run `python` command
then type `for i in range(3):`
press Enter
then press Tab once, to get to the right indentation level
then type  `for j in range(3):`
press Enter again
then press Tab twice, to get to the (expected) indentation level

if, like me, you have a Mac, chances are that the second Tab hit in the last step above, will yield 8 spaces, instead of 4

This causes problems when copying lines of code written with an IDE
(I'm using Sublime 3, with the option `translate_tabs_to_spaces` set to `True`)

I was hoping someone could identify some flag/options/setting of my interpreter which could solve this issue

Comment: maybe try to use space instead of tab?

Comment: in python you indent the code with spaces and spaces only. not tabs. Tabs are not forbidden but they have complicated rules.

Comment: There is no error in the picture you posted? Are you able to post something reproducible

Comment: Furthermore, in Python 3 a tab never equals *any* number of spaces, only tabs

Comment: It's 8 spaces in each case; the first 3 "slots" of the first tab are taken up by the primary and secondary prompts. The display of a tab is the job of the terminal, not the interpreter.

Comment: I also just checked and you can copy and run code with 8 spaces

Comment: A tab isn't really 8 spaces, either; rather, tab moves the cursor the next tab *stop*, and the tab stops occur every 8 columns. Tabs are meant to format **tab**les, not code. (In fact, tab is short for "tabulation".)

Comment: thank you all for your answers and special thanks to those who downgraded my question, which is a serious one. Unfortunately no one answered my question but repeating things I already knew or could easily find via a simple Google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title question :
Because you are at 2nd indentation level since you have a loop inside a loop.

Tabulation/space error :
Python uses only indentation to interpret which block belongs to the code. No "BEGIN...END" , no brackets. So indentation IS information.
The rule is "indentation must be uniform", so either everything is spaces (1,2,4.. as you want) or everything is tabulations.

For more information, refer to the Python style guideline (PEP8) here :

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

By using an IDE ( such as Spyder, for example) tabs will automatically be replaced by spaces. I recommend you to use one, especially if you are a new to python.

Comment: thanks for your answer. please read my edit. despite using an IDE (as you suggest), Python interpreter returns `TabError`

Comment: @andrea  `1`  : Forget about the `tab` key. Use only spaces.  `2` : Use terminal only to start a script file instead of coding in it, it will by way easier  `3` : text editors and  IDEs are two diferent things, Sublimetext is not an IDE.